# probability to get the results if coin A is not better than coin B

Tags: probability, solution-verification

In a video game there are two strategies, which have different unknown success rates. We can model them as two independent biased coins A and B.

We observed that A won (head)  7926 times out of 14531 (0.5455). and that B won 52.9% out of 24256 games.

My friend said that A has a lower sample size and therefore it's not necessarily better, I reasoned that let's assume that A had the same winrate/head probability as B, what's the probability that we get the results that we got here or better. I think the answer should be:

$\sum_{k=7926}^{14531} {{14531} \choose{k}} 0.529^k (1 - 0.529)^{14531 - k} ≈0.0000362242$ [wolfarmalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B14531%2C+k%5D+0.529%5Ek+%281+-+0.529%29%5E%2814531+-+k%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+7926%2C+14531%7D%5D)

therefore A must be better.

- is this reasoning correct?
- even if I plug in 0.54 in that equation I get 0.09 which appears way too low to me.[wolfarmalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B14531%2C+k%5D+0.54%5Ek+%281+-+0.54%29%5E%2814531+-+k%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+7926%2C+14531%7D%5D)

Comment: In general: You make a hypothesis test to decide if a coin is better than the other. Something like [this here](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda353.htm).

Comment: It's never a good idea to test for the occurrence of an exact value in a large sample.  This is nearly a continuous process, so of course the probability of seeing a particular exact value is $0$.  Do a range instead.  Assuming $A$ really has the same statistics as $B$, what is the probability of seeing *at least* $7926$ Heads in $14531$ trials?

Comment: Note:  as usual in this sort of thing, all you can really hope for is to see if your null assumption is consistent with the observed results *within some confidence interval*, which you need to set externally.

Comment: @callculus42 Thanks,  I will try to go through it But I'm having a bit of trouble because I don't know much probability

Comment: @lulu I think that's what I tried to do no? I'm summing from k = 7926 to n

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I'm surprised the number came out so low, in that case.  Failure of intuition, I suppose.  Anyway, yes.  That's the right thing to compute.

Comment: Back of the envelope:  pretending everything was normal, and that $A$ and $B$ were the same, we'd have a mean of $.529\times 14531=7687$ and $\sigma = \sqrt {.529\times (1-.529)\times 14531}=60$, so your observed result is off by $4\sigma$.  I agree that's effectively impossible.

Comment: Note: of course you should allow for some noise in the computation for $B$, but with such a large sample, that shouldn't matter much.